# Intermittent USB Port Issues 22.04 and up: Mouse movements, Keyboard strokes, Data streams, etc

Tags: usb, kernel, keyboard, mouse

I've looked thru quite a few postings that all seem to have usb mis-handling as the common issue, but no generally common solution.

20.04 had been running fine. Problems seemed to begin after upgrading to newer versions of Ubuntu (and Mint). So, why not drop back to 20.04 and stay there? Impacts workflow due to newer file formats and features.  Also, I'd really like to solve this problem.

Just to rule out hardware issues, I've replaced: the motherboard (ASUS Prime 550-Plus), drive, wifi card (and even tried ethernet only), graphics card (Radeon to Nvidia), power supply, mouse and keyboard (went from logitech wireless to generic wired).  The only hardware common to the two systems is the AMD Ryzen 5 2600X processor and memory. Memory diagnostics pass with zero errors. Ubuntu 22.04, 22.10, and 23.04, as well as Mint 21, have been installed clean. The issues seem common to both hardware configurations.

Slowing down of mouse movement and keyboard response (typing and nothing happens, to typing and long delay (2-10 seconds) to respond, to the expected response) seems to occur when:

- Chrome is active (crashpad-handler spawns ten or more processes when Chrome is running)
- a usb device, such as thumb drive, scanner, or radio (I'm an amateur radio type) is plugged into a usb port
- after typing for a period of time (works fine initially, then slowly degrades).  A restart clears this (temporarily).

I've looked at dmesg for clues.  The system monitor app helped identify Chrome as a contributing bad actor. And I really like using Chrome. System monitor doesn't seem to reflect high cpu use when things go south.

So, does anyone really know what's different between newer and older Ubuntu releases with respect to handling usb port activity?  Did the way Ubuntu handles interrupts change? Was the usb driver module library changed substantially?

Memory leak of some sort?  Interrupt handling? Malware not detectable with clamav? Temperature issues?

Constructive suggestions welcomed and much appreciated.

Comment: You provided few specific details; you mention (four) releases with two being LTS thus have kernel stack choices but you gave no specifics as to which you elected to try. You didn't mention Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server (*which have different defaults*) so being specific allows us to better understand. I often find older hardware (*we have few details though mention a CPU*) does better with older kernel stacks, newer hardware with newer stacks thus selecting the right LTS ISO can *help* or *impede* results but you didn't give specifics.

Comment: You do realize this is a Q&A site (*Question and Answer site*) and not a forum!.  Each question should deal with only a single issue and outline the specific problem with clear details; with answers being *solutions* to that problem. Your discussion on USB port however is *vast* and too broad for a Q&A format; plus there are multiple kernel stack choices for a single LTS release thus variations can exist within a release as access hardware is done by the kernel (*Ubuntu provides kernel stack choices to aid in this*) Please keep your questions to a single question

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Thanks for responding, guiverc and my apologies if the question isn't a perfect fit here.  The single issue that I'm seeking a solution for is how to fix the problem of typing on the keyboard and moving the mouse only to experience unexpected system response.  Let's just focus on Ubuntu 22.04.2 Desktop (since you ask me to be specific).  Kernel version is 5.19.0-43-generic. Whether using a wireless LogiTech K345 keyboard or a generic wired keyboard, I begin to experience erratic operation (dropped characters, delayed typing) as a logged-in session continues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After considerable troubleshooting here, I believe I've determined that this issue was being caused by the LogiTech wireless keyboard/mouse dongle.  Since I've replaced it, I haven't experienced the intermittent errors described above.